Show that the sum of the perimeters of the circles is at most $\pi \sqrt{n}$ (the lines are not allowed to cut the interior of a subpolygon).

Question: Let us divide by straight lines a quadrangle of unit area into $n$ subpolygons and draw a circle into each subpolygon. Show that the sum of the perimeters of the circles is at most $\pi \sqrt{n}$ (the lines are not allowed to cut the interior of a subpolygon).

My try
This is the strongest bound I could show...
Let the circles have radii $r_1,r_2,\dots, r_n$. Then since the circles are contained in the quadrangle we get, $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\pi {r_i}^2}\leq 1$$By the Cauchy-Shwartz Inequality this implies, $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}{2\pi r_i}\leq 2\sqrt{\pi n}$$Remark: If we showed that the sum of the areas of the circles is no more than $\frac{\pi}{4}$ then we can get the desired bound. I think this would only be true if all the subpolygons are quadrangles though.

What does it mean by "can't cut an interior subpolygon"? The moment I draw a second straight line through it, it is bound to cut atleast 1 subpolygon

Your question is unfortunately a bit ambiguously worded, however I found it quite interesting and, if I am interpreting it correctly, I have an answer. However the answer is that the inequality is false, so perhaps I am interpreting it incorrectly. I am interpreting it as dividing the quadrilateral into polygonal sub-regions in any way, with line segments.
Consider the case where all the circles have the same radius, $r$, and let our quadrilateral be the unit square. Observe that your bound is obtained by $k$ rows and $k$ columns of circles (giving $n=k^2$). Each circle has diameter $\frac1k$, so has perimeter $\frac{\pi}k$, giving a sum of perimeters
$$k^2\cdot \frac{\pi}k = k\pi= \pi\sqrt n$$
This lets us obtain the bound with the circles as small as we like. However, what we have done here is the square packing of circles, which is not optimal. It has a density of $\frac\pi4$ as opposed to the hexagonal packing's $\frac{\sqrt3}6\pi$. (diagram)
We cannot perfectly fit hexagonally packed circles into the square - there will always be extra blank space around the edges - so we cannot actually obtain this density. But by making the circles small, we can get arbitrarily close: For a small $r$, we will be able to fit
$$n \approx\frac{\sqrt3}6\pi \div \pi r^2=\frac{\sqrt3}{6r^2}$$
circles of radius $r$ inside the square. So if we take the ratio
$$\frac{n\cdot 2\pi r}{\pi\sqrt{n}}=2\sqrt{n}r$$
which your bound states should always be below $1$, we find it is
$$\approx 2\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt3}{6r^2}}r=(\frac43)^\frac14>1$$
And we can obtain values arbitrarily close to this, guaranteeing we can actually surpass your bound of $1$. Each of these circles can be inscribed inside a hexagon, in a hexagonal tessellation, in order to satisfy the requirement that each circle is in its own polygonal region.
This ultimately derives from being able to pack circles more efficiently than the square packing, which corresponds to your bound.
I wonder if it's possible to do better than $(\frac43)^\frac14$?

(+1) for the efforts

It is known that the area of an $n$-gon circumscribed about a circle of radius $R$ is at least $R^2 \cdot n \cdot \tan\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)$. Cutting the quadrangle by one straight line after the other, we determine the number of the domains produced and the sum of the angles of the domains. When we draw a new straight line, the number of polygons increases by $k$, and the sum of the angles increases by at most $2k$, depending on how many nodes of the previous decomposition the new straight line goes through. This way, if the number of sides of the polygons in the resulting decomposition is $k_{1}, k_{2}, \dots, k_{n}$, then
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n} (k_{i} - 4) \leq 0.
$$
Denote by $T_{i}$ the area of the $i$-th domain and by $K_{i}$ the perimeter of the inscribed circle. We know that
$$
K_{i}^2 \leq 4\pi^2 \cdot k_{i} \cdot \tan\left(\frac{\pi}{k_{i}}\right) \cdot T_{i}.
$$
Then
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n} K_{i} \leq \pi \cdot \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sqrt{\frac{4}{k_{i} \cdot \tan\left(\frac{\pi}{k_{i}}\right)}} \cdot \sqrt{T_{i}} \leq \pi \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{4}{k_{i} \cdot \tan\left(\frac{\pi}{k_{i}}\right)}} \cdot \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n} T_{i}},
$$
by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. Therefore, it suffices to show that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{4}{k_{i} \cdot \tan\left(\frac{\pi}{k_{i}}\right)} \geq n.
$$
If $k_{i} = 4$, then the corresponding term in the sum is just equal to $1$. If $k_{i} \geq 5$, then by $\sum (k_{i} - 4) \leq 0$, this term comes together with $(k_{i} - 4)$ triangles, and for this reason, it is enough to see that for $k \geq 5$:
$$
\frac{4}{k \cdot \tan\left(\frac{\pi}{k}\right)} + (k - 4) \cdot \frac{4}{3 \cdot \tan\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)} \leq k - 3.
$$
Since
$$
\frac{4}{3 \cdot \tan\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)} < 0.7699,
$$
it suffices to show that for $k \geq 5$,
$$
\frac{4}{k \cdot \tan\left(\frac{\pi}{k}\right)} < 0.23k + 0.079.
$$
The left-hand side is less than $\frac{4}{\pi}$, and this is enough for $k \geq 6$. When $k = 5$, the left-hand side is less than $1.11$, and the right-hand side is greater than $1.2$.
